# How replace asterisks fom a specific td table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all * asterisks with a percentage sign coming from a specific td table. The script I am using is following:

```
      $('table td').eq(8).text().replace(/\*/g, '%');
```

The script does not replace the * sign. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually setting the text on the td, you are getting it and manipulating it.
Try this:

```
var $td = $('table td').eq(8),
    text = $td.text().replace(/\*/g, '%');

$td.text(text);
```